# Depicting association between list and a class inside this list in UML

Tags: uml, collections, list

I'm making an UML class diagram representing classes used for authentication.

There are 3 classes:

- X509AuthenticationFilter
- ProviderManager
- X509AuthenticationProvider

The `X509AuthenticationFilter` HAS a `ProviderManager`.

The `ProviderManager` HAS a `List<AuthenticationProvider>`

And in this list that the manager has there's the `X509AuthenticationProvider` alongside with other `AuthenticationProvider`'s

My question is about how to display such a relation between the `ProviderManager` and the `X509AuthenticationProvider`?

The best I could come up with is just a simple association like below:

[image]

But I still do have second thoughts... Maybe there's a standard for displaying such a relationship?

Comment: So `X509AuthenticationProvider` inherits from `AuthenticationProvider`?

Comment: Yes, it does

I omitted interfaces for simplicity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, a **simple association** seems the best way to represent this relationship. You may consider indicating a `*` multiplicity.

What about the alternatives ?

- It seems that **UML composition** (black diamond) is not suitable, considering that composition implies responsibility for the lifecycle of the components, whereas your constructor suggest that the list and its elements could be used somewhere else. (btw, you’d consider adding a  `« Create »` before your constructor)
- You could consider **shared aggregation** (white diamond), but [I would not advise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67425850/3723423) it: although very popular for expressing a “HAS A” relationship, the UML specification leave its semantic unspecified, and the UML founders called it a “[modeling placebo](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AggregationAndComposition.html)”. It has no advantage to use it over a simple association, unless you work in the context of a team that defined a context-specific semantic.

If you’re in UML hardcore you could consider using the [dot notation](https://www.omg.org/ocup-2/documents/getting_it_right_on_the_dot.pdf) at the end of the arrow, in addition to your current notation.

Comment: Hello, thanks a million for the answer!
So, should I just add an asterisk to the arrow pointing from `ProviderManager` to `X509AuthenticationFilter`?

Comment: @JoeD an asterix on the side of the arrowhead that points from `ProviderManager` to `X509AuthenticationProvider`

Answer (score 2):

For more completeness, and since  `AuthenticationProvider` is the Base, you may consider

- an association with multiplicity (*) from `ProviderManager` to `AuthenticationProvider`
- Show a derived relation between `AuthenticationProvider` and `X509AuthenticationProvider`
- Show a direct association from `ProviderManager` to `X509AuthenticationProvider`